# SSH disconnects when connecting to VPN

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, openvpn

Very strange one this I just cannot put my finger on it.

My old laptop with windows 10 I use at work. I use the work Ethernet connection and then connect to an SSH tunnel through mobaxterm on port 443. I then use sockscap to push the vpn client "IBVPN" through the ssh tunnel. This works perfectly using the openvpn tcp protocol and I have internet access.

Got my new laptop also windows 10. I have the exact same setup.

However on connecting to the openvpn server the SSH instantly drops out and the vpn drops connection. I can understand why it would if it is changing the ip address for the whole machine ie trying to push the ssh server through the newly acquired vpn address.

However why is this not the case on the first machine, it runs perfectly through the vpn over the SSH tunnel is there a way to stop the vpn forcing the mobaxterm application through the new IP address?

I have searched everywhere and tried every setting and cannot come up with a solution.

If anyone has any idea of where the issue is I would be extremely grateful?

Cheers,

Steve

Comment: Hmmm.....seems like once you establish the VPN tunnel, the SSH connection that tunnel relies on tries to use the tunnel. To help narrow things down, can you please make all connections/tunnels you described, open command prompt, run `route print`, and add the output to your question. If you indeed have the aforementioned problem, this table will show that the preferred way to reach the other side of your SSH tunnel after VPN is dialed is via VPN. Obviously this will not work. We can correct this with some vpn client settings.

Comment: This is the working laptop route print [link](https://justpaste.it/3bwl5)

Comment: This is the non working one. I manged to print the route quickly before it disconnected the tunnel [link](https://justpaste.it/3bwl5)

Comment: Ouch...that is hard to read with the missing whitespace. give me a minute to read this.

Comment: You pasted the link to the same clipboard twice. Can you try again?

Comment: Andy apologies should be this one [link](https://justpaste.it/2rm5n)

Answer (score 0):

You have an invalid route marked below. This probably isn't the root cause but it is an issue. There is no way to reach the gateway 10.10.210.1 from the IP 10.44.210.77. This may be causing your issue as it creates conflicting route information for your new default gateway.

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination   Netmask           Gateway         Interface       Metric
0.0.0.0               0.0.0.0           10.44.210.254   10.44.210.77    25
0.0.0.0               0.0.0.0           10.10.210.1     10.44.210.77    537 <<<
0.0.0.0               128.0.0.0         10.10.210.1     10.10.210.4     36
10.10.210.0           255.255.255.0     On-link         10.10.210.4     291
10.10.210.4           255.255.255.255   On-link         10.10.210.4     291
10.10.210.255         255.255.255.255   On-link         10.10.210.4     291
10.44.210.0           255.255.255.0     On-link         10.44.210.77    281
10.44.210.77          255.255.255.255   On-link         10.44.210.77    281
10.44.210.255         255.255.255.255   On-link         10.44.210.77    281
88.150.220.171        255.255.255.255   10.44.210.254   10.44.210.77    26
127.0.0.0             255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1       331
127.0.0.1             255.255.255.255   On-link         127.0.0.1       331
127.255.255.255       255.255.255.255   On-link         127.0.0.1       331
128.0.0.0             128.0.0.0         10.10.210.1     10.44.210.77    26
224.0.0.0             240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1       331
224.0.0.0             240.0.0.0         On-link         10.10.210.4     291
224.0.0.0             240.0.0.0         On-link         10.44.210.77    281
255.255.255.255       255.255.255.255   On-link         127.0.0.1       331
255.255.255.255       255.255.255.255   On-link         10.10.210.4     291
255.255.255.255       255.255.255.255   On-link         10.44.210.77    281
===========================================================================
```

The correct route is shown on the other machine. The correct interface IP is used.

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination   Netmask           Gateway         Interface       Metric
0.0.0.0               0.0.0.0           10.44.210.254   10.44.210.73    25
0.0.0.0               0.0.0.0           10.10.210.1     10.10.210.4     547 <<<
0.0.0.0               128.0.0.0         10.10.210.1     10.10.210.4     36
10.10.210.0           255.255.255.0     On-link         10.10.210.4     291
10.10.210.4           255.255.255.255   On-link         10.10.210.4     291
10.10.210.255         255.255.255.255   On-link         10.10.210.4     291
10.44.210.0           255.255.255.0     On-link         10.44.210.73    281
10.44.210.73          255.255.255.255   On-link         10.44.210.73    281
10.44.210.255         255.255.255.255   On-link         10.44.210.73    281
88.150.220.171        255.255.255.255   10.44.210.254   10.44.210.73    26
127.0.0.0             255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1       331
127.0.0.1             255.255.255.255   On-link         127.0.0.1       331
127.255.255.255       255.255.255.255   On-link         127.0.0.1       331
128.0.0.0             128.0.0.0         10.10.210.1     10.10.210.4     36
224.0.0.0             240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1       331
224.0.0.0             240.0.0.0         On-link         10.10.210.4     291
224.0.0.0             240.0.0.0         On-link         10.44.210.73    281
255.255.255.255       255.255.255.255   On-link         127.0.0.1       331
255.255.255.255       255.255.255.255   On-link         10.10.210.4     291
255.255.255.255       255.255.255.255   On-link         10.44.210.73    281
===========================================================================
```

If you run these commands, it will fix the route error. However this is not a permanent fix. For now, just run the commands as soon as you can after connecting VPN and see if it fixes the problem.

```
route delete 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 10.10.210.1
route add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 10.10.210.1 IF <correct_number>
```

where `<correct_number>` is the number listed in your ROUTE PRINT next to the interface with the IP address 10.10.210.4 (I cannot tell which interface that is from what you posted). You might be able to get things working with only the first command; this route is technically redundant to the next route in the list.

If this fixes the problem, then we will need to look at your OpenVPN client and server config files to figure out why the wrong interface is selected on your second machine. I would be very curious what 'push' commands are listed in the server configuration, and perhaps they push an ambiguous route that is interpreted differently on the second machine. You have more interfaces on the second machine and the configuration might only have worked on the first machine by luck.

Let me know if it isn't clear what we are doing and I can try to explain in more detail.